# Getting TypeError :arguments did not match any overloaded call while trying to return a variable and use variable in a PyQT6 grid.addWidget

Tags: python, return, typeerror, pyqt6

I'm trying to use a pyqt6 combo box to load a selection into a variable so I can use it elsewhere.  Not sure why I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\python_projects\pac_org\main2.py", line 115, in <module>
    main()
  File "e:\python_projects\pac_org\main2.py", line 111, in main
    ex = Example()
  File "e:\python_projects\pac_org\main2.py", line 9, in __init_ _self.initUI()
  File "e:\python_projects\pac_org\main2.py", line 74, in initUI grid.addWidget(lblPStyleR, 3, 0, color('red'))
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  addWidget(self, QWidget): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
  addWidget(self, QWidget, int, int, alignment: Qt.AlignmentFlag = Qt.Alignment()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
  addWidget(self, QWidget, int, int, int, int, alignment: Qt.AlignmentFlag = Qt.Alignment()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
```

I've tracked the issue to the line
`grid.addWidget(lblPStyleR, 3, 0)`
This line is supposed to input the value of the variable self.tstPTypeR into Row 3 Column 0.  I've tried entering self tstPTypeR directly into the grid.addWidget statement but get the same error.  Not sure what I'm missing. Tried adjusting the `super().__init__` statement with no results.  Complete code below:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit, QGridLayout, QApplication, QComboBox)
import sys

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.tstPStyleR = str("0")
        self.tstPTypeR = str("0")
        #self.strPLoc = 0
        #self.strAIMVer = 0

        lblPSN = QLabel("PAC Serial Number: ")
        ledPSN = QLineEdit()
        
        lblPType = QLabel("PAC Type: ")
        cboPType = QComboBox(self)
        cboPType.addItems(["Single", "Double", "Triple"])
        cboPType.textActivated[str].connect(self.onPTypeActivate)
        self.lblPTypeR = QLabel("Single", self)

        lblPStyle = QLabel("PAC Style: ")
        cboPStyle = QComboBox(self)
        cboPStyle.addItems(["3x Fuse, 1x 48v", "3x Fuse, 2x 48v", "0x Fuse, 1x 48v", "0x Fuse, 2x 48v"])
        cboPStyle.textActivated[str].connect(self.onPStyleActivate)
        self.lblPStyle = QLabel("3x Fuse, 1x 48v", self)

        lblPLoc = QLabel("PAC Location: ")
        cboPLoc = QComboBox(self)
        cboPLoc.addItems(["PAC Cell", "PAC Cell: Repair", "Blue Line", "Frame"])
        cboPLoc.textActivated[str].connect(self.onPLocActivate)
        self.lblPLoc = QLabel("PAC Cell")

        lblAIMSN = QLabel("AIM SN: ")
        ledAIMSN = QLineEdit()

        lblAIMVer = QLabel("AIM Version: ")
        cboAIMVer = QComboBox(self)
        cboAIMVer.addItems(["GREEN 1.4", "RED 2.0", "RED 3.0"])
        cboAIMVer.textActivated[str].connect(self.onAIMVerActivate)
        self.label = QLabel("GREEN 1.4", self)

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(10)

        grid.addWidget(lblPSN, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(ledPSN, 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(lblPType, 1, 2)
        grid.addWidget(cboPType, 1, 3)
        grid.addWidget(self.lblPTypeR, 1, 4)
        grid.addWidget(lblPStyle, 1, 5)
        grid.addWidget(cboPStyle, 1, 6)
        grid.addWidget(self.lblPStyle, 1, 7)
        grid.addWidget(lblPLoc, 1, 8)
        grid.addWidget(cboPLoc, 1, 9)
        grid.addWidget(self.lblPLoc, 1, 10)

        grid.addWidget(lblAIMSN, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(ledAIMSN, 2, 1)
        grid.addWidget(lblAIMVer, 2, 2)
        grid.addWidget(cboAIMVer, 2, 3)
        grid.addWidget(self.label, 2, 4)
        self.setLayout(grid)

        lblPStyleR = str(self.tstPStyleR)
        #lblPTypeR = self.strPTypeR
        #lblPLocR = self.strPLoc
        #lblAIMVerR = self.strAIMVer

        grid.addWidget(lblPStyleR, 3, 0)
        #grid.addWidget(self.strPTypeR, 3, 1)
        #grid.addWidget(lblPLocR, 3, 2)
        #grid.addWidget(lblAIMVerR, 3, 3)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Stratacache PAC Manager")
        self.show()
   
    def onPStyleActivate(self, text):
        self.tstPStyleR = text
        print(self.tstPStyle)
        self.lblPStyle.setText(text)
        self.lblPStyle.adjustSize()
        return self.tstPStyleR

    def onPTypeActivate(self, text):
        self.tstPTypeR = text
        print(self.tstPTypeR)
        self.lblPTypeR.setText(text)
        self.lblPTypeR.adjustSize()


    def onPLocActivate(self, text):
        self.strPLoc = text
        self.lblPLoc.setText(text)
        self.lblPLoc.adjustSize()
        return self.strPLoc

    def onAIMVerActivate(self, text):
        self.strAIMVer = text
        self.label.setText(text)
        self.label.adjustSize()
        return self.strAIMVer

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

The message states that you're trying to call `addWidget` but aren't providing the right argument type:

```
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  addWidget(self, QWidget): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
  addWidget(self, QWidget, int, int, alignment: Qt.AlignmentFlag = Qt.Alignment()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
  addWidget(self, QWidget, int, int, int, int, alignment: Qt.AlignmentFlag = Qt.Alignment()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
```

`addWidget` expects a `QWidget`, but for this particular instance you're calling it with a `str` rather than a `QWidget` subclass:

```
# your code
lblPStyleR = str(self.tstPStyleR)
grid.addWidget(lblPStyleR, 3, 0)
```

You need to create a `QLabel` out of `lblPStyleR`:

```
lblPStyleR = QLabel(self.tstPStyleR)
grid.addWidget(lblPStyleR, 3, 0)
```